# How to change structure of RDD/Spark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

What is the easiest procedure to go from this kind of rdd/spark dataframe:

| date | Tokyo | New York |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01 | 1 | 2 |
| 02/01 | 3 | 2 |
| 03/01 | 4 | 5 |

to the same data in this form below?

| city | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tokyo | 01/01 | 1 |
| New York | 01/01 | 2 |
| Tokyo | 02/01 | 3 |
| New York | 02/01 | 2 |
| Tokyo | 03/01 | 4 |
| New York | 03/01 | 5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this with `pyspark sql` using functions like `create_map` and `explode`

As below -

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func

df1= df.withColumn('mapCol',
                    func.create_map(func.lit('Tokyo'),df.Tokyo,
                                    func.lit('New York'),df["New York"]
                                   ) 
                  )

res = df1.select('*',func.explode(df1.mapCol).alias('city','value')).drop("Tokyo", "New York", "mapCol")
res.show()
```

**Output :**

```
+-----+--------+-----+
| date|    city|value|
+-----+--------+-----+
|01/01|   Tokyo|    1|
|01/01|New York|    2|
|02/01|   Tokyo|    3|
|02/01|New York|    2|
|03/01|   Tokyo|    4|
|03/01|New York|    5|
+-----+--------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler solution, using [stack](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#stack)

`apache-spark-sql`

```
with t (date, Tokyo, `New York`) as (select stack(3 ,'01/01',1,2 ,'02/01',3,2 ,'03/01',4,5))

-- The solution starts here

select date, stack(2, 'Tokyo',Tokyo,'New York',`New York`) as (city,value)
from   t
```

| date | city | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01 | Tokyo | 1 |
| 01/01 | New York | 2 |
| 02/01 | Tokyo | 3 |
| 02/01 | New York | 2 |
| 03/01 | Tokyo | 4 |
| 03/01 | New York | 5 |

`pyspark`

```
df = spark.sql("select stack(3 ,'01/01',1,2 ,'02/01',3,2 ,'03/01',4,5) as (date, Tokyo, `New York`)")

#The solution starts here
df.selectExpr("date", "stack(2, 'Tokyo',Tokyo,'New York',`New York`) as (city,value)").show()
```

---

```
+-----+--------+-----+
| date|    city|value|
+-----+--------+-----+
|01/01|   Tokyo|    1|
|01/01|New York|    2|
|02/01|   Tokyo|    3|
|02/01|New York|    2|
|03/01|   Tokyo|    4|
|03/01|New York|    5|
+-----+--------+-----+
```